# Back Button Running Amok

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

On each of my app pages I am setting the back button's functionality, since I want it to do different things each time. However, when I run this on one page:

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, a) =>
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    a.Handled = true;
};
```

It also runs the back button's function on another one of my pages *if* that page has been visited first. This throws an exception, since it tries to unload a nonexistent project. Is this not the correct way to set the back button's functionality per page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct behavior as `SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView()` returns the same `SystemNavigationManager` as it's still the same view (not page!) and you then have two event handlers attached to the event.

If you want to have specific event handlers per page, use `OnNavigatedTo` to add and `OnNavigatedFrom` to remove the event handler:

```
public class BackButtonPage : Page
{
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        BackButtonVisibility = base.Frame.CanGoBack ? AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible : AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;

        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += BackButtonPage_BackRequested;

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -= BackButtonPage_BackRequested;
    }

    private void BackButtonPage_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnBackRequested(sender, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        //your page specific code here
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    public AppViewBackButtonVisibility BackButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility; }
        set { SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = value; }
    }
}
```

([source from Microsoft's examples on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Notifications/cs/Notifications/Helpers/BackButtonPage.cs))

Comment: Ah! I'd assumed the handlers were disposed when the page was navigated from.